# Implementing C strcpy but getting segfault

Tags: c, cstring

I'm trying to implement strcpy within my main but I'm not sure why I'm segfaulting on the first while loop. Could someone shed light?

```
int main()
{
    const char* src = "this is a test";
    char* dest = "abcdefgqwerty";
    char* head = dest;
    while(*dest++ = *src++);
    while(*head++)
    {
        printf("%c", *head);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char* dest = "abcdefgqwerty";` is read-only.

Comment: Well, if you mean you truly want to implement your version of `strcpy` that mimics the runtime function, then what you implemented is correct.  The runtime function will also go haywire on bad input.

Answer (score 1):

These is not enough room in the destination for what you are copying. The declaration of `dest` only contains 14 bytes but you need 15.

Answer (score 1):

`dest` variable points to the string literal, which in reality resides in read-only memory region. That's why you can't copy into it.

To test your `strcpy()` implementation, I'd recommend declaring strings as arrays:

```
char dest[256] = "abcdefgqwerty";
```

Comment: The runtime version of `strcpy` would also go nuts on a string literal destination.  So that's why I asked the OP whether what they originally implemented is acceptable.